# How do access different tables in the database without creating entities in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.4

I have a table with 3 columns EmployeeNum, JobTitleCode and cost. I have made an entity for it with basic CRUD functions.

EmployeeNum and JobTitleCode are both Foreign Keys and when displaying the entity I want to be able to query another table in the database to extract EmployeeName from EmployeeNum and JobTitle from JobTitleCode.

In Symfony 1.4 I could just do Doctrine_Core::getTable('Employees').find('EmployeeNum') by defining 'Employees' in the schema but I couldn't find any similar method in Symfony 2.4.

From the [API](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Registry.html) for getDoctrine() I didn't find any similar methods I could use and if I build a query as such:

`createQuery('SELECT a FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number=1')`

I get the error below

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'hs_hr_employee': Error: Class 'hs_hr_employee' is not defined
```

So how do  you go about accessing data from other tables in the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine always tries to map your results to entities by default.

You can use a **[prepared statement](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements)** without the need to provide a result-mapping:

**get the connection:**

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
```

---

**preparing a statement and executing it:**

```
$statement = $connection->prepare(
    'SELECT a FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number = :emp'
);
$statement->bindValue('emp', $emp);
$statement->execute();

// for SELECT queries 
$result = $statement->fetchAll('EAGER');  // note: !== $connection->fetchAll()!

// for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries
$affected_rows = $statement->rowCount();
```

This is pretty expressive. See the examples below for shorter variants.

---

**Alternative:**

Use a **[Native SQL query](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class)** with a result-mapping.

Advanced example shows how to rename columns in the result-array.

```
// create a result-mapping
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addScalarResult('n', 'nickname');
$rsm->addScalarResult('f', 'muchachos');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery(
    '
     SELECT 
        users.name as n
        COUNT(user.friends) as f
     WHERE
        users.name = :username_parameter
     FROM
        user_table_name users
    ',
    $rsm
);
$query->setParameter('username_parameter', $username); 

$result = $query->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

// example: $username = 'nifr'
// array => [ 
//   'nickname'  => 'nifr'
//   'muchachos' => 3919410
// ]
```

---

**Shorter versions**: (*letting doctrine prepare the statement + directly fetch result*)

```
// for SELECT queries
$result = $connection->executeQuery(
    'SELECT a FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number = ?'
    array($emp)
);

//for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries
$affected_rows = $connection->executeUpdate(
    'DELETE FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number = ?',
    array($emp)
);

// fetch all into array ( <numeric-index> => <associative-array-entry> )
$connection->fetchAll(
    'SELECT a FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number = ?',
    array($emp)
);
// fetch only first-row of result-set as associative array
$connection->fetchAssoc(
   'SELECT a FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number = ?',
    array($emp)
);
// fetch only first-row of result-set as array with numeric indexes
$connection->fetchArray(
    'SELECT a FROM hs_hr_employee a WHERE a.emp_number = ?',
    array($emp)
);
```

---

**Even shorter variants** (*for of INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries*)

```
// DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ? (1)
$conn->delete('user', array('id' => 1));

// INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?) (nifr)
$conn->insert('user', array('username' => 'nifr'));

// UPDATE user (username) VALUES (?) WHERE id = ? (nifr, 1)
$conn->update('user', array('username' => 'nifr'), array('id' => 1));
```

---

Useful links:

- [Using prepared statement](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements)
- [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html)
- Statement (interface) [API doc](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.2/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Driver.Statement.html)
- Statement (interface) [Code](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Statement.html#256-271)

Comment: splendid. Thank you